# Difference Between Strings and Names on VBA. Strings referencing ranges on different sheets

Tags: string, vba

Hello again Stack OverFlow Community! I am a very big noob to VBA still but trying to figure out whats going on here. I pieced together some of my code for you guys below. Im working in the sheet Data but everytime I run the code below I get an error on line "Set Banks = DataS.Range("X9:X11")" saying that I cant use the DataS.Range part of the code. If I use it without DataS.Range Im good.

What Im trying to figure out is why I can assign TypofDeal a range no problem but I cant assign Banks the same range even though there both strings.

The code eventually will need to be able to assign Banks to DS.Range("X9:X11") which is a similar range but on a different sheet.

The internet told me to use a Names.Add function but I dont understand why I need to!! What is the difference between a "Name" and a "String"!!

Thanks guys!!

```
Dim DS As Worksheet
Set DS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Design") 
Dim DataS As Worksheet           
Set DataS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Dim TypeofDeal As String, Banks As String                              
Dim Bank As Range, Label As Range, Line As Range    
Set Line = DataS.Range("V22:W22")                     
TypeofDeal = DataS.Range("W21")                        
Banks = DataS.Range("X9:X11") 

If TypeofDeal = "Purchase" Then                     
    Line.Delete     

Else
Line.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Set Label = DataS.Range("V22")                        'Variable
Set Bank = DataS.Range("W22")                         'Variable

Label.Select
Selection.Value = "Financing Company"
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Bank.Select
Bank.Value = " "
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Formula1:="=" & Banks                       
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThick
Selection.Borders.ColorIndex = 23

End If
```

Comment: In your code sample you do not use `Set ` just `Banks = DataS.Range("X9:X11")`.

Comment: There is no need to work with named ranges but they are quite useful.  You should read [The VBA Guide To Named Ranges](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/the-vba-guide-to-named-ranges).

Comment: You should google [wiseowltutorials excel vba introduction](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS291US303&ei=k9I6W9rvH8zt5gKp3Z_oAg&q=wiseowltutorials+excel+vba+introduction&oq=wiseOwlTutorials+Excel+VBA+Intro&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i21k1.14947.19590.0.21914.16.16.0.0.0.0.244.2428.0j5j7.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.12.2419...0j35i39k1j0i20i263k1j0i30k1j0i22i30k1j33i160k1.0.k5LuT6iHTvA).   This video series is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error on this:

```
Banks = DataS.Range("X9:X11")
```

but, not on this:

```
TypeofDeal = DataS.Range("W21")
```

Is because:

```
TypeofDeal = DataS.Range("W21")
```

is only using the value from one cell, which is valid. Whereas this:

```
Banks = DataS.Range("X9:X11")
```

is an attempt to assign the values from 3 cells to one string, which is not valid.

If you need to add the values from all three cells to the same string, you could do something like this:

```
Banks = DataS.Range("X9").Value & DataS.Range("X10").Value & DataS.Range("X11").Value
```

If that alone doesn't solve your problem, I'll need to see the data that would be in the cells in question and then I can test your whole solution and perhaps provide a more thorough answer.

Also, I don't see any substantial benefit to using a named range in this scenario, at least, not based on the code you've provided.

Comment: Gotcha. Whats really crazy is the code works with Banks = ("X9:X11")!!! Isn't that strange?! And the Name. function was the only one that validation list code will accept if the data is on another sheet. Otherwise the Banks = ("X9:X11") code works fine

Comment: Weird. When I try `Banks = ("X9:X11") `, Banks only returns "X9:X11", not the actual data in the cells.